# ExecutorService - How to interrupt exectuion of threads which have been invoked from main thread after an exception inside one of them

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have class `SomeService`. Its methods can be invoked from *different threads*(for example from RestController).
This class contains `ExecutorService` and some `CustomClass`.

```
public class SomeService {
   private ExecutorService service;
   private CustomClass customClass;

   public SomeService(ExecutorService service, CustomClass customClass){
       this.service = service;
       this.customClass = customClass;
   }

   public void servicePost() {
      CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(urls.size());
      for (String url : List<String> urls){
          service.submit(() -> {
              customClass.send(url);
              countDownLatch.countDown();
          });
      }
      countDownLatch.await();
   }
}
```

I want to execute `customClass.send(url)` parallel in different threads using `ExecutorService` but this method can throw `RuntimeException`.

For example, I submitted 5 tasks:
1. 2 tasks is successfully executed
2. 2 tasks are running.
3. one of them throws RuntimeException.

**How can I interrupt tasks which are running?**
**p.s**. ExecutorService can have tasks from other threads. I don't want to interrupt them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `shutdownNow()` on the executor service when you catch the exception, also you need to check `Thread#interrupted()` inside the task before the processing. Your code should look something like below:

```
service.submit(() -> {
        if (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            try {
                  customClass.send(url);
                  countDownLatch.countDown();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   service.shutdownNow();
                }
        }

    });
```

Comment: But if executorService is executing tasks from another main thread - will It not interrupt them?

Comment: For example I need to save url after execution customClass.send(url). When some of threads invokes service.shutDown() it's possible to lose url - information about exectuion. Another thread could execute customClass.send(url) and after its thread could become interrupted